¿Cómo soluciono el ERROR 1442 que me arroja al ejecutar un procedure que actualiza?
Necesito un procedure que actualice la columna fkMembresia, pero al hacerlo me genera error 1442 y llevo tiempo tratando de entender porque da ese error. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias
+++++++ Mi tabla ++++++++++++
Table: clienteMembresia
Columns:
pkIdClienteMem  int UN AI PK 
fkCliente       int UN 
fkMembresia     int UN
fechaExpiracion date 
activo          tinyint

-- Mi codigo ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
PROCEDURE `updRangoCliente`(idClienteP int, idMemP int)
updRC:begin 
    
    if (idMemP = 1) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'La suscripcion/socio (1) no es un rango';
        leave updRC; 
    end if;

    -- actualizamos el rango del cliente
    update clienteMembresia
    set fkMembresia = idMemP
    where fkCliente = idClienteP
    and fkMembresia !=1;
end


¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. A tu publicación le falta el mensaje de error (que en ocasiones explica mejor que el código la situación). Dado el tipo de error, sospecho que también falta que cuentes desde dónde estás llamando a este procedimiento almacenado, probablemente esté involucrado un trigger sobre la tabla clienteMembresía y eso sea el origen de tu problema.

Lo ideal es un [mcve] con el que quien quiera responderte pueda reproducir el problema (completo), contenga solo el código esencial para reproducirlo (mínimo) y así tenga un punto de partida para una posible respuesta. Eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.

¿Estás ejecutando ese procedimiento en un trigger de clienteMembresia? Esto no es posible porque no puedes modificar datos en una tabla el precisamente el mismo momento que te informe un trigger que los datos de la tabla se están modificando.
